# How to get the Elements of a pdf using iText java

Tags: itext

I have trouble in getting a element from pdf i.e., Signature and I want to append signature image beside the Signature Field.

I found that it is not AcroField.

[image]

Comment: If there is no AcroField, there is no signature field. Your question contradicts itself. Remove all references to "field" and "signature". You want to find a specific word in a PDF file and you want to add an image next to that word, more specific on a line that is drawn next to that word. That's not trivial. It requires more programming than I have time to explain in an answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Srinivas *You want to find a specific word in a PDF file and you want to add an image next to that word* - You'll find numerous questions and answers here concerning text extraction with coordinates. That's your starting point.